# y ticks cutting off in matplotlib in ipython

Tags: matplotlib, plot, ipython

I am drawing a `matplotlib` graph in `ipython` but my `y-ticks` are getting cut off. [image]

I tired to use `plt.tight_layout()` and `plt.autoscale()` but both do not seems to work. How do I get the ticks to be shown fully?

The code that I have is: `set1` and `set2` are lists of same size

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mpld3

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.canvas.draw()
x = np.arange(1,len(set1)+1,1)

ax.scatter(x, set1, c='blue', s=200, alpha=0.5)
ax.scatter(x, set2, c='red', s=200, alpha=0.5)
ax.grid(color='lightgray', alpha=0.7)
plt.xlim(0,500)
plt.tight_layout()
#plt.autoscale()
mpld3.display(fig)
```

Comment: Post some code, please. Much easier.

Comment: @gustafbstrom I have posted my current code

Comment: Looks fine. What is `mpld3`?

Comment: @gustafbstrom http://mpld3.github.io/

Comment: Are the ticks cut off if you use `plt.show()` instead?

Comment: @gustafbstrom yes. besides that I need to use `mpld3.display(fig)` as mpld3 provides interactivity in plot in browser which is not provided in basic `matplotlib` plot and is critical to my need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could adjust where the edges of the axes object is with [`subplots_adjust`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust)

For example

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)  #Adjust 0.2 to find the right margin for your plot
```

I think that `tight_layout` will override this setting, so you may need to turn that off.